# restart SAX parser from the middle of the document

Tags: java, python, c++, xml, sax

I'm working on a project that needs to parse a very big XML file (about 10GB). Because process time is really long (about days), It's possible that my code exit in the middle of the process; so I want to save my code's status once in a while and then be able to restart it from last save point.

Is there a way to start (restart) a SAX parser not from the beginning of a XML file?

P.S: I'm programming using Python, but solutions for Java and C++ are also acceptable.

Answer (score 1):

Not really sure if this answers your question, but I would take a different approach. 10GB is not THAT much data, so you could implement a two-phase parsing.

Phase 1 would be to split the file in smaller chunks based on some tag, so you end up with more smaller files. For example if your first file is `A.xml`, you split it to `A_0.xml`, `A_1.xml` etc.

Phase 2 would do the real heavy lifting on each chuck, so you invoke it on `A_0.xml`, then after that on `A_1.xml` etc. You could then restart on a chunk after your code has exitted.

Comment: How to split the XML file so there will not be error?